# Show that $\frac{a+b}{1 + ab} < 1$ for $a,b < 1$

Tags: inequality

I'm currently solving a physics problem which comes down to show that
$$
\frac{a + b}{1 + ab} < 1
$$
for $0 < a,b < 1$. I tried some numbers and it seems to hold. I tried replacing $1$ by $ab$ or $a, b$ by $1$ but then the inequality immediately breaks down. The problem looks really simple so a small hint would be enough I guess.

Comment: Indeed, $-1<\frac{a+b}{1+ab}<1$ if $-1<a<1$ and $-1<b<1$.  The inequalities boil down to $(1-a)(1-b)>0$ and $(1+a)(1+b)>0$.  Is it a special relativity problem?  Alternatively, $\tanh(x+y)=\frac{\tanh(x)+\tanh(y)}{1+\tanh(x)\tanh(y)}$ with $-1<\tanh(x),\tanh(y)<1$.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes it is. I'm showing that a lorentz boost will keep $v < c$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $1+ab>0$ and  $1+ab-a-b=(1-a)(1-b)$

Answer (score 0):

we have to prove that $$\frac{1+ab-a-b}{1+ab}>0$$ for $$0<a,b<1$$ this is true since $$1+ab-a-b=(1-a)(1-b)>0$$ and $$1+ab>0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try multiplying both sides by $1+ab$. That should smooth things out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

start with a<1, and b<1,
=> (a-1)<0
=> (b-1)<0;
multiply both

(a-1)(b-1)>0;
expand
a*b-a-b+1>0
=> (ab+1)/(a+b)>1
now reciprocate it you will get (a+b)/(1+ab)<1